# What is the way to invert a triangular matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix-inverse, triangular

I have an upper triangular matrix and I'd like to compute its inverse in a fast way. I tried `qr.solve()` but I have the feeling that it's equivalent to `solve()`, and that it does not exploit the triangular nature of the input matrix. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: It's best if you provide some sample input and expected output to make sure that those who are willing to provide possible answers are answering the right question.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough. I'm only looking for a function name, or failing that, an algorithm to compute the inverse of a triangular matrix in an efficient way.

Comment: `qr.solve` and `solve` are not equivalent in the sense you seem to imply. The first uses a QR decomposition and the second uses an LU decomposition. Why do you want an inverse? If you want to solve a triangular system, have a look at `backsolve` and `forwardsolve`.

Comment: In fact, I have already obtained my upper triangular matrix R with a QR decomposition. All I want is to compute efficiently R^-1.

Comment: This is only an example of solving a matrix equation, not of a matrix inversion.

Answer (score 4):

Try `backsolve()` and use the identity matrix with appropriate dimension as the right-hand value.

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- 2000
n.cov <- 1000
X <- matrix(sample(c(0L, 1L), size = n * n.cov, replace = TRUE), 
            nrow = n, ncol = n.cov)
R <- chol(crossprod(X))
rm(X)
microbenchmark(
  backsolve = backsolve(r = R, x = diag(ncol(R))),
  solve = solve(R),
times = 10)

Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 backsolve 467.2802 467.5142 469.4457 468.1578 468.6501 482.2431    10
     solve 748.2351 748.8318 750.0764 750.3319 750.9583 751.5005    10
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the inverse of your matrix `M`, you can simply use `backsolve(M, diag(dim(M)[1]))`. For example:

```
M  <-  matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10) # random matrix
M[lower.tri(M)]  <- 0 # make it triangular
Minv <- backsolve(M, diag(dim(M)[1]))
M%*%Minv
```

When running this code you may see `M%*%Minv` with very low coefficient (~10^-15) due to numerical approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I have, of late, confronted the same problem. My solution has been to load the Matrix package, and then define the following two R functions serving as wrappers for that task:

```
my.backsolve <- function(A, ...) solve(triu(A), ...)  
my.forwardsolve <- function(A, ...) solve(tril(A), ...)
```

These need the Matrix package because `triu`and `tril` are defined in it. Then `my.backsolve(A)` (resp. `my.forwardsolve(A)`) computes the inverse of `A` for the upper (resp. lower) triangular case. 
A minor issue, though, might be that the result of each of the above two R functions is of class `Matrix`. If one has issues with that, then apply `as.vector` or `as.matrix`to the result according to whether the r.h.s. is a vector or a matrix (in the algebraic sense).

Answer (score 0):

It seems `solve` performs somewhat faster than `qr.solve` but `qr.solve` is more robust.

```
n <- 50
mymatrix <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=n)

fun1 <- function() {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    mymatrix[i, i:n] <- rnorm(n-i+1)+3
  }
  solve(mymatrix)
}

fun2 <- function() {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    mymatrix[i, i:n] <- rnorm(n-i+1)+3
  }
  qr.solve(mymatrix)
}

> system.time(for (i in 1:1000) fun1())
   user  system elapsed 
   1.92    0.03    1.95 
> system.time(for (i in 1:1000) fun2())
   user  system elapsed 
   2.92    0.00    2.92
```

Note that if we remove the `+3` when editing the matrix cells, `solve` will almost always fail and `qr.solve` will still usually give an answer.

```
> set.seed(0)
> fun1()
Error in solve.default(mymatrix) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.3223e-22
> set.seed(0)
> fun2()
[returns the inverted matrix]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tests, but I'm not sure that <pre>qrsolve</pre> actually exploits the triangular form of the input matrix. It must try to decompose it into a QR form. Though, there are specific (and FAST) algorithms designed to invert such matrices.

Answer (score -1):

The R base function `chol2inv` might be doing the trick for inverting triangular matrix. Inverts a symmetric, positive definite square matrix from its `Choleski decomposition`. Equivalently, compute `(X'X)^(-1)` from the (R part) of the `QR decomposition of X`.
Even more generally, given an upper triangular matrix R, compute `(R'R)^(-1)`.
See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chol2inv.html

I tested its speed by microbenchmark method: qr.solve is slowest, solve ranks 3rd in speed, backsolve ranks 2nd in speed, chol2inv is the fastest.

> cma <- chol(ma  <- cbind(1, 1:3, c(1,3,7)))
>
> microbenchmark(qr.solve(ma), solve(ma), cma<-chol(ma), chol2inv(cma), invcma<-backsolve(cma, diag(nrow(cma))), backinvma<-tcrossprod(invcma))

Comment: `chol2inv(M)` does not return the inverse of `M` (even when `M` is triangular)